$KK$ doesn't commute with arbitrary products
Let $A$ be a $C^\ast$-algebra which is not $K_*$-contractible, i.e., $KK(A,A)$ is non-zero.
Then is it true that the natural map
$KK(A,\prod_{\mathbb{N}}A) \rightarrow \prod_{\mathbb{N}}KK(A,A)$ is not an isomorphism? The case of $A=\mathbb{C}$ is discussed in Ideas for calculating $K_0(l_{\infty})$ and $K_1(l_{\infty})$. , but the details aren't clear to me, and also it is not clear how to generalise this argument to a general $C^\ast$-algebra. Any help would be appreciated.
